# How do I wrap div border exactly around the text in Ref 1?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

I'm trying to get the div box to wrap exactly around the text content, but it seems the div is larger than it needs to be which will look ugly as this is supposed to be a black coloured translucent tooltip.

How do I ensure that the div border wraps exactly around the content while allowing me a max-width of about 350px or maybe allow break-all for long words only, but not other words.

While this may be a duplicate, it's the only one which has an image and is easier to digest for those with limited time but also wants to seek a solution to this. There has been no perfect solution to this so far (based on my search).

Ref 2 and Ref 3 just shows why break-all doesn't work out for me.

*Data are randomly rewritten to protect privacy. I appreciate your help and try not to mark this as duplicate. Please take note that the content of this tooltip is from 1 word to 1 long paragraphs and may contain short word and very long word(such as a URL).*

[image: How to wrap div border exactly around the text in ref 1]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.a {
  max-width:350px;
  word-break: normal;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.b {
  max-width:350px;
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.c {
  max-width:350px;
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>How to wrap div border exactly around the text in ref 1?</h1>
<p>It should not look like I added padding to the right inside the div box.</p>

<h2>Ref 1: The div border is larger than it is wrapped around the text. I can't have the space on the right.</h2>
<div class="a">Are you a new user? Register at https://statlink.iedacsignature.com.co/</div>

<h2>Ref 2: break-all, works but not for more than 2 lines.</h2>
<div class="b"> This div contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword.</div>

<h2>Ref 3: break-all, breaks all the words not just the long ones only.</h2>
<div class="c"> This div contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. This div contains a very long word. This div contains a very long word. This div contains a very long word. This div contains a very long word</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is not possible with CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by giving a `display: inline-block` and `word-break: break-all` to your div

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it but it doesn't solve the issue for Ref 3. Other words that are not long will also be broken down. The content of this tooltip is variable.